# which command is used to check if a button is enabled or disabled using selenium IDE.

Tags: selenium-ide

You can not click a button unless you edit at least one field, and button will be disabled. once you edit any field the button 'reset' will be enabled to click.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in a number of ways.

Probably one of the more useful ways (If you are using this fact more than once), is to save the "status" of the button to a variable.

Below are two separate examples of how you could code this.

The first example will take a variable called isSelected, and assign it either a value of "block" or "none" dependent on how the selector is displaying.

The second example will look at the radio button and see whether it is present in the "On" state or not.

**This first one uses the jQuery addon**

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>jQuery('div.search-date-container div.modal').css('display')</td>
    <td>isSelected</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>storedVars['isSelected']=='block'</td>
    <td>skipToDatepicker</td>
</tr>
```

**This second one doesn't**

```
<tr>
    <td>storeElementPresent</td>
    <td>id=edw_paynow</td>
    <td>edwPresent</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${edwPresent}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>${edwPresent}==false</td>
    <td>skipEDW</td>
</tr>
```

You may need to adapt the code slightly - but I don't know what buttons you are using. If you provide a bit more info and an upvote I'm sure I could try figure it out :)